# Can't connect to Postgres when running .Net 5 API in Docker container

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, .net-core

I'm trying connect a .Net 5 API running in a Docker container with a Postgres db running in a separate container. The connection works when running the API locally without a container, however when I run the API in a container I get the error

An error occurred using the connection to database 'databasename' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'.

I think this is because the docker container is not running on localhost.
I have attempted to change the host in the docker-compose file and tried manually changing the connection string in startup.cs. This changes the connection the API uses when run locally, however does not change the connection within the container, or the error I am getting. Any help would be appreciated.

Startup.cs

```
//var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(PostgresSettings)).Get<PostgresSettings>().ConnectionString;
var connectionString = $"Host=tryingtochangehost;Port=5432;Database=databasename;Username=username;Password=password";
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
services.AddScoped<IDataContext>(provider => provider.GetService<DataContext>());
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - JWTCONFIG:SECRET=secret
      - POSTGRESSETTINGS:PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRESSETTINGS:HOST=postgresql_database
    depends_on:
      - "postgresql_database"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  postgresql_database:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=databasename
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin@admin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes:
  database-data:
  pgadmin:

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "PostgresSettings": {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": "5432",
    "Database": "databasename",
    "Username": "admin"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "JwtConfig": {},
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to connect to `localhost:5432`, you're trying to connect to the same container as your web container.

Docker compose creates a virtual network where each container can be reached by it's service name. So you need to change the database server name from `localhost` to `postgresql_database` like this in your appsettings:

```
{
  "PostgresSettings": {
    "Host": "postgresql_database",
    "Port": "5432",
    "Database": "databasename",
    "Username": "admin"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "JwtConfig": {},
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Your connection string code should be

```
var connectionString = $"Host=postgresql_database;Port=5432;Database=databasename;Username=username;Password=password";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Changing the connection string or appsettings is only effecting the api when it is not running in a container. Even manually changing the connection string e.g services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("notarealconnectionstring")); is only causing an effect when running the API without a container. It seems no matter what the string actually is, the container tries to connect to the database at  tcp://localhost:5432,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my configuration was fine, however I needed to run docker-compose build before docker-compose up so the changes actually had effect.